# Issue with scanf_s causing no output and unexpected debugging exit in Code::Blocks C program

Tags: c, codeblocks

I'm encountering an issue while writing a C program in Code::Blocks. Although the program runs without errors, it doesn't produce any output when I use the scanf_s("%c %c %c", &a, &b, &c); statement, and it always unexpectedly exits during debugging at the scanf_s statement. How can I resolve this issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;
    scanf_s("%c%c%c",&a,1,&b,1,&c,1);
    printf("%c %c %c\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeD2h.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijNSw.png)I'm new to C programming, and I attempted to modify the statement to scanf_s("%c%c%c", &a, 1, &b, 1, &c, 1);, which resulted in successful program execution. Could you please explain why this change resolved the issue?

Comment: Works on my end, with GCC installed from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075). But I would just avoid `scanf_s` (and other `_s` functions) and use `scanf`.

Comment: It's here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-170 It says: `Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require you to specify buffer sizes for some parameters. Specify the sizes for all c, C, s, S, or string control set [] parameters`. So you have to specify size for `c` using the method which this function expects.

Comment: The "safe" or "secure" functions (with the `_s` suffix) was added because of Microsoft, which introduced them and which are really the only ones that use them. One major problem is that the functions as specified by the C specification *differ* from the implementation by Microsoft themselves. Despite that they should be portable, they are not. Unless you're required to use them, my suggestion is that you don't.

Comment: With that said, even [this general `scanf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) say that the `%c` format expects a *pair* of arguments, with the second being the size. If you don't pass the correct and expected arguments to a function, you should not expect them to work.

Comment: Don't use `scanf_s`, just use `scanf`. The `_s`stands for "secure", but on your level , security is not something you need should worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `"%c"` with `scanf_s()` expect 2 arguments, a pointer (`char *`) and size (`int`)
- Better code would check the result value.
- OP may want a leading space to consume *whitespaces*.
- Consider using `fgets()` as an alternative to reading a line of input from the user.

```
if (scanf_s(" %c%c%c",&a,1,&b,1,&c,1) != 3) {
  printf("Oops\n");
} else {
  printf("%c %c %c\n", a, b, c);
}
```